# perl only to find and replace exact match

Tags: perl, pattern-matching, replace, substitution

I am trying to implement substitution in perl.
I have a binary matrix and I would like to replace

0 with 1

and

1 with 2.

So i used the following line

```
s/1/2/g foreach @remaining;
```

However, this command ends up replacing my column names as well which has numbers in it. it converts, for example, 1234 to 2234.

I want it to match and replace only 1s and not 1234.

Comment: Perhaps you should say something about your data, besides it being a binary matrix, such as, is it stored in a plain file, tab/comma separated, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use word boundaries like:

```
s/\b1\b/2/g foreach @remaining;
```

To replace 0 and 1 at the same time:

```
s/\b([01])\b/1+$1/eg foreach @remaining;
```

Comment: Thanks M42. It is working. Can you also please explain to me how does it work? what is the function of \b? For the first one you used \b1 and for the second one\b/2. why are they different?

Comment: @user1007742 `\b1` and `\b2`... no, they don't exist. :) The escape sequence is `\b`, the numbers are just numbers. The `\b` word boundary is a zero-width assertion that asserts that its position is a boundary between a word character and a non-word character.

Comment: @TLP thanks, I think i got it \bword\b is the exact match. thanks

Comment: @TLP: Thanks for comment, I couldn't reply before.